Receiver Email Not Showing in Firestore Messages Collection
I'm working on a chat application using Flutter and Firebase. I'm trying to save and retrieve messages between users, including the receiver's email, but the receiver email is not appearing in my Firestore collection. Here is my code:
ChatPage.dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = "ChatPage";

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late User? signedInUser;
  TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSignedInUser();
  }

  void getSignedInUser() {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      signedInUser = user;
    });
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String message, String receiverEmail) async {
    try {
      if (signedInUser != null) {
        final messageData = {
          'message': message,
          'senderId': signedInUser!.uid,
          'senderEmail': signedInUser!.email,
          'receiverEmail': receiverEmail,
          'timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
        };

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').add(messageData);
        _messageController.clear();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending message: $e');
    }
  }

  String formatLastSeen(DateTime lastSeen) {
    Duration difference = DateTime.now().difference(lastSeen);
    if (difference.inDays > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inDays} days ago';
    } else if (difference.inHours > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inHours} hours ago';
    } else if (difference.inMinutes > 0) {
      return 'Last seen ${difference.inMinutes} minutes ago';
    } else {
      return 'Last seen just now';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final name = args['name'];
    final imageLink = args['ImageLink'];
    final lastSeenTimestamp = args['lastSeen'];
    final receiverEmail = args['receiverEmail'];

    // Convert Firestore Timestamp to DateTime
    DateTime? lastSeenDateTime;
    if (lastSeenTimestamp != null && lastSeenTimestamp is Timestamp) {
      lastSeenDateTime = lastSeenTimestamp.toDate();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageLink),
        ),
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(name),
            Text(
              lastSeenDateTime != null ? formatLastSeen(lastSeenDateTime) : 'Last seen unknown',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('messages')
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  );
                }

                final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: messages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final message = messages[index];
                    final messageText = message['message'];
                    final senderId = message['senderId'];
                    final isMe = signedInUser?.uid == senderId;

                    return MessageReplay(
                      sendmessage: messageText,
                      isMe: isMe,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _messageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Type a message...',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final message = _messageController.text.trim();
                    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
                      sendMessage(message, receiverEmail);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageReplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? sendmessage;
  final bool isMe;

  const MessageReplay({Key? key, this.sendmessage, required this.isMe})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 5,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: isMe ? Radius.circular(30) : Radius.circular(0),
              bottomRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            color: isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Text(
                sendmessage ?? 'Message not found',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


screen shot for Messages collection

Despite including the receiverEmail in the messageData map, the receiverEmail field is not appearing in my Firestore collection. Here are the steps I've taken:
I pass the receiver email as an argument to the ChatPage and retrieve it using ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments.
I include the receiverEmail field in the messageData map when sending a message.
The receiverEmail field should be stored in Firestore along with the other message data.
Actual Behavior The receiverEmail field is missing in the Firestore messages collection.

Are you passing the email using routes? Please check that.

Navigator.pushNamed(context,    ChatPage.screenRoute,arguments: {    'name': doc.get('name')?? 'No name',     'ImageLink': (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)?['image_link'] ?? '',       },       ); this my routes, how can I passing the email????
